# Styled Components not working after npm run build

Tags: styled-components

I'm building a website using styled components. It works fine in my local environment but as soon as I run npm run build it no longer works on the hosted site. I have the latest version of styled components installed as a dependancy. The styled components names work but none of the styles are coming through.

[This is how the Website looks in my local dev environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYGTq.png)

[This is how it looks after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7tfM.png)

heres a link to the website after being posted
https://benmcloughlin.github.io/savvy-plan-lite/
here's a link to the github repository
https://github.com/BenMcLoughlin/savvy-plan-lite

Answer (score 2):

I spent three hours rebuilding the app and deploying it after each change to determine where the issue was. It had to do with GlobayStyles, one of the styled-components features. If I was using global styles then nothing worked. If I removed global styles then it worked. I have no idea why but I just removed it and will no longer use it. Just wanted to answer my own question in case someone came across the same issue.